# C# json object Deserializtion

Tags: c#, json, weather-api

*I have a JSON content as*

```
[{
    "LocalObservationDateTime": "2018-04-23T08:10:00+05:00",
    "EpochTime": 1524453000,
    "WeatherText": "Sunny",
    "WeatherIcon": 1,
    "IsDayTime": true,
    "Temperature": {
        "Metric": {
            "Value": 29.6,
            "Unit": "C",
            "UnitType": 17
        },
        "Imperial": {
            "Value": 85.0,
            "Unit": "F",
            "UnitType": 18
        }
    },
    "MobileLink": "http://m.accuweather.com/en/pk/jamaluddinwali/259991/current-weather/259991?lang=en-us",
    "Link": "http://www.accuweather.com/en/pk/jamaluddinwali/259991/current-weather/259991?lang=en-us"
}]
```

*my class to handle this content is as follow:*

```
class AccuWeather
{

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public DateTime LocalObservationDateTime { get; set; }
        public int EpochTime { get; set; }
        public string WeatherText { get; set; }
        public int WeatherIcon { get; set; }
        public bool IsDayTime { get; set; }
        public Temperature Temperature { get; set; }
        public string MobileLink { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
    }
```

*I just tried to deserialize this content by the following code snippet in C#:*

```
       private AccuWeather.RootObject Parse_A(string targetURI)
       {
        Uri uri = new Uri(targetURI);

        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();

        AccuWeather.RootObject wUData = null;

        try
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                // if you want all the "raw data" as a string
                // just use: responseData.ToString()

                wUData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccuWeather.RootObject<Class1>>(responseData);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

        return wUData;
    }//completed
```

I am not sure enough that this is the proper and efficient way to deserialize JSON content. Can anybody provide some detail information on best practices in this case?
Any help is appreciated in advance!

Comment: Ask something perhaps?

Comment: Since your JSON is an array, have you considered deserializing to an array rather than an object? JSON.Net expects your C# objects to match the JSON structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use .NET dynamics for this e.g

```
var json = @"[{""LocalObservationDateTime"": ""2018-04-23T08:10:00+05:00"",
                ""EpochTime"": 1524453000,
                ""WeatherText"": ""Sunny"",
                ""WeatherIcon"": 1,
                ""IsDayTime"": true,
                ""Temperature"": {
                    ""Metric"": {
                        ""Value"": 29.6,
                        ""Unit"": ""C"",
                        ""UnitType"": 17
                    },
                    ""Imperial"": {
                        ""Value"": 85.0,
                        ""Unit"": ""F"",
                        ""UnitType"": 18
                    }
                },
                ""MobileLink"": ""http://m.accuweather.com/en/pk/jamaluddinwali/259991/current-weather/259991?lang=en-us"",
                ""Link"": ""http://www.accuweather.com/en/pk/jamaluddinwali/259991/current-weather/259991?lang=en-us""
            }]";

dynamic accuWeatherResp = JArray.Parse(json);
if (accuWeatherResp.Count == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Response is Empty");
    return;
}
dynamic weather = accuWeatherResp[0];
if (weather != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Observation time: {0:s} Weather: {1}, Temperature: {2: 0.0} °C", weather.LocalObservationDateTime, weather.WeatherText, weather.Temperature.Metric.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Terry love you. You have also save my time for making their string formats....

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a page called [quicktype.io](https://quicktype.io/) where you can paste your JSON and receive C# classes and the corresponding converter code:

```
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public partial class Welcome
{
    [JsonProperty("LocalObservationDateTime")]
    public DateTimeOffset LocalObservationDateTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("EpochTime")]
    public long EpochTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("WeatherText")]
    public string WeatherText { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("WeatherIcon")]
    public long WeatherIcon { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("IsDayTime")]
    public bool IsDayTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Temperature")]
    public Temperature Temperature { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MobileLink")]
    public string MobileLink { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }
}

public partial class Temperature
{
    [JsonProperty("Metric")]
    public Imperial Metric { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Imperial")]
    public Imperial Imperial { get; set; }
}

public partial class Imperial
{
    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public double Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Unit")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("UnitType")]
    public long UnitType { get; set; }
}

public partial class Welcome
{
    public static Welcome[] FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome[]>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
}

public static class Serialize
{
    public static string ToJson(this Welcome[] self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
}

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters = {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
    };
}
```

Comment: What question did you answer?

Comment: The question "how to deserize this , i have tried."